# An example of normalization of scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Qing liu. 123 Exercise 1.7

Let $k$ a field. Determine the normalization of $Proj$($k[x,y,z]/<x^3-y^2z>$)

how to prove it ?

First, i divided a case to 3 parts corresponding standrad cover for Projective scheme.

and then I don't know how to do

Just i have to know a process of finding the integrally closed domain?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful to state what your thoughts and attempts on the problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : normality is a local condition. Show that for a curve, $x \in X$ is normal if and only if $x$ is smooth. There is only one singular point, you need to find a resolution of singularity of $X$. You can try to find a parametrization $f : \Bbb P^1 \to X$ since it has genus zero, or compute explicitly the blow-up of the curve.

Comment: thanks, but there is no other direction? just by assuming that we only know normality, but dont know blow up and concept of regularity       by the way i think i can  a picture of normality a little bit thanks to you

Comment: This is a very standard lemma. Since normality is local, with the lemma (smooth $\Leftrightarrow$ normal) you can show that $[0:0:1]$ is the only no normal point. In affine coordinates this is the curve $Y = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb A^2 : y^2 = x^3 \}$. You can compute the normalisation $\tilde Y$ by finding the integral closure of $\mathcal O(Y)$.